# 0-380V Dimmer Circuit using MOC series Optotriac

Tags: power

I want design a dimmer circuit that have output voltage of 0-380V(rms). I didnt see any application about 380 V dimmer circuits and there is no information about 380V application in MOC series opto datasheets. But some optotriacs allow application for 380 V such that VO3062 or IL410 in their datasheets.

The 380 V (single phase) is produced from 220 to 380V transformer in my application. I have designed a dimmer circuit for 0-220V before and it worked perfectly. This circuit is below. I want use again these components and this circuit.

[image]

But now I want control 0-380 V output and I dont know what will be resistors of circuits. I think they will not change because of resistor value is related with input voltage of MOC3061 (VCC is 5V and current must be 15 mA for MOC3061 series ). Can I use again MOC3061 and BT137 for control of 0-380 V dimmer circuit?

Comment: I would rather switch to HV opto triac without trying with MOC rated for 240VAC.

Answer (score 2):

The resistors don't look like their values are all that important, really, as long as the parts can take the extra voltage (and any surges or spikes which could occur) it's probably ok, just test it with a small load to make sure it's working ok first